# Why typeof does not check inheritance of class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

how to make an example work? Why i can not use typeof in this example and what can it be replaced with?

```
abstract class Check {
    constructor(public field: number) {
    }
}

class Check1 extends Check {
    field1: number;
    constructor(field: number, field1:number) {
        super(field);
        this.field1 = field1;
    }
}

abstract class CheckUser {
    abstract getConstructor(): typeof Check;
}

class Check1User extends CheckUser{
    getConstructor(): typeof Check {
        return Check1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `typeof Check` means you have to return a type that has all the statics of `Check` but also have a constructor with the same arguments as that of `Check`. Since `Check1` has another argument to it's constructor it will not be assignable to the type of the `Check` constructor.

You can remove the extra parameter from `Checked1` and the assignment will work ([ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=20&pln=6&pc=29#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgCwKawGsEBvAWACgEqkB7AO0igFd4aoAKAByZGQEtYCAGZ9cyACYAuBHSYBbELigBKEhWoIAvhW3kKKNBhz4CARgS4AHhFx1xRvITWVqseoxYQ27EWKkz5RRVnDQ0wJk4lH1EJZQBudWpdXQpQRjhEA3QsRwIAVTAlEOo06AyEAHNcCEx3aE9vZWkIAE9ImiEckwTyFPIshxNTAqKrGztBwhGoMhcqKpq65lYOJoRW9s7jJ1nQ6ihqpig6LsJTHo1koA))

You could also change the base class to take a generic type argument that must be a constructor that returns `Checked`:

```
abstract class CheckUser<T extends new (...a: never[]) => Check> {
    abstract getConstructor(): T;
}

class Check1User extends CheckUser<typeof Check1>{
    getConstructor() {
        return Check1;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgCwKawGsEBvAWACgEqkB7AO0igFd4aoAKAByZGQEtYCAGZ9cyACYAuBHSYBbELigBKEhWoIAvhW3kKKNBhz4CARgS4AHhFx1xRvITWVqseoxYQ27EWKkz5RRVnDQ0wJk4lH1EJZQBudWpdXQpQRjhEA3QsRwIAVTAlAB4AFQtrW3sZXAB3BHYAOibgaTpcADclAG0AXVUAXgA+HJNhshcqNOgMhABzXAhMd2hPb2VpEoTyFPIshxNTAqVymzt9wiOoIogAT0iaIRHCU0HxjXnF5eZWDlU30KoUAWTCgdCeZi2GmSQA)

There might be other options as well but it depends what you want to do with `getConstructor` afterwards.